# Make Parent Div Retain Original Size When Interior Divs Are Hidden

Tags: html, css, visibility

I have an exterior parent div with two child divs within. I want to hide both of the child divs until the user scrolls to certain section of the page, at which point, the divs will fade in. How can I make the parent div retain its size when the interior divs have their visibility attribute set to hidden?

Comment: if you use `visibility:hidden` the size is retained. Only if you use `display:none` size varies..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 visibility:hidden
```

The HTML element takes space but is not visible. The element is simply transparent, so to speak.

```
 display:none
```

The HTML element does not hold its space and is not visible.

**visibility:hidden** is probably what you want

Comment: Just realized my issue was something else entirely. When I'm about to fadeIn the divs, I hide them first, then call the fadeIn() function. However, this call to hide causes some strange behavior and that was causing me issues.

Answer (score 1):

Bishal is right, another approach that you could use is to animate the opacity property and in both cases (either using visibility or opacity), you can set an animation to produce the fade in effect:

**The CSS:**

```
.element {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Then you can target your `.element` on scroll with JS and set the opacity property to 1 (the transition property will ensure the fade in).